# Is there a way to get ruby text to convert to HTML text, for indexing purposes? or how do I get the index of text in HTML accurately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selection, range

[image]

In the above image, I've selected the phrase 'macro up myself' which starts at index 140, and ends at index 155.
(Indexes are calculated via .outerHTML of the parent element (the div holding all the text))

[image]
Now, here in the second image, you can see that the span (the part that creates the light blue highlight in the HTML screenshot) isn't placed where it should be. Also, make note of the numbers in teh top left. The start index is the same, and the end index is just the end index from the first picture + the length of `<span class="cha... ...50">`

How I get the indexes:
From the javascript side: (like in the first picture)

```
   start_index = parent_element.html().indexOf(selection[0].outerHTML) - 33; // already have a large arbitrary offset, but I'd prefer to know why the indexes aren't lined up.
   end_index = start_index + html.length;
```

These indexes are passed along to the rails server, where it should insert spans into the text, but the indexes don't match the location of the span highlight in the HTML.

So my question is: how do I get an accurate index?

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing.

Comment: how can I better clarify? basically indexes HTML don't match indexes of the same text stored server side.

Comment: I think a basic problem I'm having is understanding what you mean with your use of the word "index".

Comment: That's a tough one.  I was going to recommend wrapping based on regex detection (where you can ignore all the html tags) instead of index, but this would require you to detect which instance of the match to wrap. (i.e. if you tried to wrap the phrase 'i am' and 'i am' shows up 8 times)

Comment: @Pointy: well, just.. the index of a substring within a string.  The string being a parent DOM element. and the substring being a child DOM element.

Comment: @rkw Don't worry about repeat substrings, I surround my selected text with a very specific span, so it's easy to find.

Comment: Serialized HTML you get from the DOM (via `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`) does not necessarily precisely match the equivalent initial HTML sent by the server. That being the case, trying to do this in this way is futile.

Comment: @TimDown the other way I can think of is just to send the entire containing element to the server, overwriting the original html stored on the server. Is that the proper way to go about that?  I mean, how would I handle two different users modifying the same html at the same time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339157/javascript-regexp-match-text-ignoring-html

Comment: @TheLindyHop It sounds like you're building an [EtherPad](https://github.com/ether/pad) clone.. [Operational Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) is how this is done to handle multiple users manipulating the DOM at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a cleaner version of the text to work with (you've got white space in there, it looks like). Something like:

`start_index = $.trim(parent_element.text())`

On the ruby side you may need to do the same thing to make sure you have no whitespace on either one. Also your output shows some html entities (`&#39;`), so in the ruby code you might need to make sure you're working with the indexes of the string *before* the special characters get html-encoded.