# Searching the text on website

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Respected Members,

I am designing the website in pure HTML with the help of one Template.

In that i have one textbox[search] and Go button.

I want to make operation such that when any one types certain text and presses Go button,
It should highlight the text in that website which is matching to that text.

How can i do that?

Than You.

Comment: try this [http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

Comment: try this http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

Comment: @viveksalve : ok. changal example aahe. amrit_neo yanch answer ekada check kara. te implement hou shakel ka?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchItem').keyup(function(){
            var name = $(this).val();
            var pattern = name.toLowerCase(); 
            var targetId = ""; 
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("item"); 

            $(document).find('.item').hide();

            $('.item').each(function(i){
                var para = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("p"); 
                var index = para[0].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern); 
                if (index != -1) { 
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will work. The actual html tags are not visible to the user, but will be returned if we use this. For eg: var position = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('<p>'); will return a valid index but is not actually visible to the user in the web page

Answer (score 5):

You didn't posted what you have. I think this is what you are mentioning.

Check this. I can do this for you but you have to do it in your ideas

```
function highlightInElement(elementId, text){
var elementHtml = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
var tags = [];
var tagLocations= [];
var htmlTagRegEx = /<{1}\/{0,1}\w+>{1}/;

//Strip the tags from the elementHtml and keep track of them
var htmlTag;
while(htmlTag = elementHtml.match(htmlTagRegEx)){
    tagLocations[tagLocations.length] = elementHtml.search(htmlTagRegEx);
    tags[tags.length] = htmlTag;
    elementHtml = elementHtml.replace(htmlTag, '');
}

//Search for the text in the stripped html
var textLocation = elementHtml.search(text);
if(textLocation){
    //Add the highlight
    var highlightHTMLStart = '<span class="highlight">';
    var highlightHTMLEnd = '</span>';
    elementHtml = elementHtml.replace(text, highlightHTMLStart + text + highlightHTMLEnd);

    //plug back in the HTML tags
    var textEndLocation = textLocation + text.length;
    for(i=tagLocations.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var location = tagLocations[i];
        if(location > textEndLocation){
            location += highlightHTMLStart.length + highlightHTMLEnd.length;
        } else if(location > textLocation){
            location += highlightHTMLStart.length;
        }
        elementHtml = elementHtml.substring(0,location) + tags[i] + elementHtml.substring(location);
    }
}

//Update the html of the element
document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = elementHtml;
}

highlightInElement("fatDoggie","The dog is really really fat");
```

This fiddle was made to highlight a set of text instead you should get the variable in search and place in the `highlightInElement("Element","Var");`

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7339157/1716774

Comment: Yeah. I exactly wanted this.http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/JyL4J/ Thank you for recomending good website

Comment: I am glad to help my friend

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old post, but the jsfiddle in the post was not available anylonger. One problem with the above code, is that it does not catch and remove tags such as <button type="button">. Any thoughts on what the regex should be to only capture full tags?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have a one-page site? In this case, the entire content is already loaded on the page, and you just want to search through it. You can do it quite easily using Javascript and JQuery. Just catch the click on the button, and traverse the DOM looking for your string, then do domething on that (for example, scroll until there, or highlight it).

If you have more than one page, then this will be more challenging, as you don't have all your content available client-side. A server-side searching solution would be better in this case.