# local visible text search on current web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html

I need to do a local search visible text on a single simple html page. Users can simply use Ctrl+F to do that, but I would like to add a search box on the page to do the search instead. I thought of a couple ways to do this:

1- By forcing the browser's Find tool when a button on the page is clicked.

2- By a javascript/Jquery plugin that do LOCAL search on the current page.

I searched for both solutions but was not able to find anything useful. Does anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you searching just visible text? Source code? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Visible text. I edited my question to specify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching the text on website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799154/searching-the-text-on-website)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word, might be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a common class name to the tags that contains the display text and perform a search based on that class name. I had attached a link for your reference. you can make use of that funtion and call that function from a button click. 
[Generic Search in HTML Page](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/11/javascript-search-text-html-page/)