# Push button for launch "search of browser"

Tags: html, spring, google-chrome, button, search

I would like to know if a button can be placed on a web page corresponding to the ctrl + F command to open the search for the browser.If it is not possible there is one way to insert the search function for html text elements quickly and quickly. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13799273/5264501

Comment: Im so newbie can u help me with an example

Comment: Someone can help me?

Comment: the link I posted has an answer to your question - I haven't tested the answer on that page

Comment: i want an example, i have already read this post

Comment: if I knew another answer, I would have posted it