# regexp finds html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a simple 'search function' using jQuery. you type some text in a box and it returns the text on the page you searched. However, if I type the word 'the' the search results come back with `<thead></thead>` with 'the' highlighted. How can I make it so it doesn't find html tags like those? A similar thing happens when I type 'edit' and it returns an image named 'edit....' with the image disappeared and 'edit' highlighted.

I tried a few different things with the line starting with element, as I think that's where the problem lies.

```
        function highliter(word, id){
            $('*').removeClass('highlight');
            var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
            var repl = '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/word/g, repl);
            // element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);

            $('html, body').scrollTop($(".highlight").offset().top - 126);
```

Comment: [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)?

Comment: You need to be doing the search on text, not html, but then that presents problems when replacing it, if there are embedded html elements as you explain.  Nested elements make this even more difficult.  This is a rather large minefield.

Comment: @gcampbell - replacing texContent would not allow the html to be part of the replacement string :p

Comment: @Archer, yea I see that now. I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong or this is how it's meant to act

Comment: What about the [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)?

Comment: @Arnauld can you give an example on how to use it with my code? I'm not able to get it working

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as a duplicate question until you've had a look at this page... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339157/javascript-regexp-match-text-ignoring-html

Answer (score 0):

Well. To be honest, I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution, but it does the job and hopefully will give you some ideas.

It works in two steps:

- first process **text nodes** of all elements that contain the target word and replace it with a special markup (which should be unlikely to be found anywhere else in the source code -- this is the hack that I'm not very happy with)
- then replace our markup with the final replacement pattern, using a regular expression and the html() method (this part is very similar to your original one)

```js
function highliter(word, id) {
  var el = $('#' + id);
  var repl = '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';
  
  $('*').removeClass('highlight');
  recursiveMarker(word, el);
  el.html(el.html().replace(/\[MY_MARKUP\]/g, repl));
}

function recursiveMarker(word, parent) {
  var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  var repl = '[MY_MARKUP]';

  parent.find(':contains(' + word + ')').contents().each(function(key, el) {
    if(this.nodeType == 3) {
      el.data = el.data.replace(rgxp, repl);
    }
    else {
      recursiveMarker(word, $(el));
    }
  });
}

highliter('div', 'container');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color:#ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>This is a div <span id="div">with a span whose id is 'div'</span></div>
  <div>This is another div</div>
</div>
```